# my python code is not working.....i want to find if the entered list contains duplicate items

Tags: python

I want to use this function to find duplicate items in my list, but this code is not working:

```
p = "enter a list\n"
t = raw_input(p)
def has_duplicate(t):
   o = sorted(t)
   i = 0
   while i < len(o):
       if o[i] == o[i + 1]: 
           print "the list has duplicates"
       elif o[i] != o[i+1]:        
           i += 1
       if i >= len(o):
         print "the list has no duplicate"
```

It gives me an error saying `has_duplicates` not defined.

Comment: Looks like the function's name is `has_duplicate` (singular), not `has_duplicates` (plural)

Comment: you are using wrong function name use `has_duplicate(t)` that would resolve your problem, whenever the error comes please try to read out the error and try to resolve the error at your own, if the error is not common and very severe then post the question .

Answer (score 2):

As @mgilson commented, your issue is you are calling the function incorrectly (`has_duplicates` vs `has_duplicate`) however...

The most straight forward way to do this is using a `set` and comparing `len`.

```
def has_duplicates(t):
    return len(set(t)) != len(t)
```

If you take an iterable and wrap it in a `set` you will end up with only unique items. If the length of the set is the same as your original iterable then you have no duplicates. If the length is different (will always be equal to or smaller) then you have duplicates which were removed when converting to a `set` type.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you do `list_name.sort()`.
Other easy way to find duplicates is

```
len(your_list)!=len(set(your_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be calling function `has_duplicates` but you have defined `has_duplicate` function.

try to call `has_duplicate`